# How to compile a class in to Jdk 1.1 version which was in Jdk 1.6?

Tags: java

I have a .class file which is in jdk 1.1 version. When i tried to compile in Jdk 1.5 and 1.6, it shows BadClassVersionError.

So I tried for jdk 1.1 version. I am unable to get it from anywhere.
Except from sun's java site. but when I try to install, its not installing.

As I searched google, I came to know that there is an other option
so that we can compile our class in 1.1 version.

**Hello.java is my java file. and my current version is jdk 1.6**

When I use the below command:

```
javap -verbose Hello
```

It shows **minor version : 0**
and **major version   : 50**

Now I used the below command :

```
javac -target 1.5 Hello.java
```

It works correctly. Now it shows major version as **49**.

But the problem is when I try the same command with **target 1.1**.

```
javac -target 1.1 Hello.java
```

It's not working, it shows the below error:

> javac: target release 1.1 conflicts with default source release 1.5

Is the command usage wrong?

Comment: What is your OS? And what are the problem with the installation of jdk 1.1? The archive on Sun web site should work fine.

Comment: Mine is Windows O.S. My machine already contains jdk 1.6 version. i downloaded jdk 1.1 version which is an .exe file from sun site. When i try to install the exe file. after 38 % it shows a dialog box error contains no information.

Comment: `This is too urgent for me. Badly i need the solution.` This just encourages people to flame you.  Every one on any forum would like a response quickly.  Given people do this for free, you can't expect too much.

Comment: @user1076011, Java 1.1. is so old, you may have to install an older OS on an older hardware to get it to work.  It hasn't been supported for a decade. Try it on Windows 95 (in a virtual machine if you have it) and it should work.

Comment: You start by talking about a `.class` file and `BadClassVersionError` and then start talking about compiling a `.java` file. Which are you having a problem with?

Comment: Thanks to all..especially to Neil, I solved the problem by using the javac -source 1.1 -target 1.1 Hello.java. but the problem solved is instead of -source 1.1 , i changed to -source 1.2. rest is same. and it worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add -source 1.1 to your commandline

```
javac -source 1.1 -target 1.1 Hello.java
```

Comment: Thanks Neil for suggesting.. i will check it and come back u if i have problem wit u ..

Comment: You still need a compile which supports such an old version of Java. Java 1.1 was released in 1997. You may have trouble finding a version of Java that runs on a modern OS. ;)

Comment: Thanks to all..especially to Neil, I solved the problem by using the javac -source 1.1 -target 1.1 Hello.java. but the problem solved is instead of -source 1.1 , i changed to -source 1.2. rest is same. and it worked